# Drupal: Active Menu Item

Tags: php, drupal, menu

I've been reading around, and I haven't quite found the answer to this yet. 
I am developing a site that has specific styling for a menu item when it is active, that is, when the user is navigating around that menu item and any part of the submenu. I want that CSS styling to stay consistent based on the menu item in the "Primary Links" menu, regardless of the URL, nodes, or what have you.

My question is this:
Is there a way to ask Drupal to identify specifically what the active menu item is, in the "Primary Links" menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the active menu item/trail by classes Drupal adds to the HTML elements.  The actual link (`<a>`) of the active item will have a class of `active`, while any parent list items (`<li>`) of the active item will have a class of `active-trail`.  See an example of a menu block below:

[image: Menu Block Code]

(Right click -> Open Image in New Tab, to see a better quality image)

Not sure if this is what you mean, but it could give you a way to style your active trail/active item.